# Запись смайликов в поток

Tags: c#, .net

Как записать смайлики в поток  ? И затем как их получить, чтобы были именно смайлики

Comment: О каком потоке речь?

Comment: binarywriter записывает в MemoryStream

Answer (score 3):

Превратить их в массив байтов: https://ideone.com/387N4i

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("")
```

Comment: При получении `System.ArgumentException: Буфер выходных символов не достаточен для хранения зак
одированных символов, кодирование 'Unicode (UTF-8)' резерв 'System.Text.DecoderR
eplacementFallback'.`

Comment: @АлександрКиселев, https://ideone.com/387N4i. Попробуй обновить .net.

Comment: не помогло мне увы

Comment: @АлександрКиселев, какая ОС и какая версия .net?

Comment: Windows 7, .net 4.8

Answer (score 3):

Я не понял смысла проблемы.

В комментариях вы упомянули, что используете `BinaryWriter` для записи в `MemoryStream`.
Просто используйте `BinaryReader` для чтения из потока.

```
string input = "";

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, leaveOpen: true))
{
    binaryWriter.Write(input);
}

memoryStream.Position = 0;

using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream))
{
    string output = binaryReader.ReadString(); // здесь получим исходную строку
}
```

Comment: Возможно, смысл проблемы в комментарии под моим ответом.